# How to increase validation accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My val-accuracy is far lower than the training accuracy. What might be the reasons for this?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I added a dropout(0.3) and reached 71% val-accuracy!
what else could be done?

Answer (score 3):

Seems your problem is all about **overfitting**. To understand what are the causes behind overfitting problem, first is to understand what is overfitting.

- One resource is in the [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-are-overfitting-and-underfitting-in-machine-learning-a96b30864690) about overfitting.

To eliminate this issue, there are several things you should check. Especially for your model:

**1)** Are you using **dropout**? Check [dropout](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-for-regularizing-deep-neural-networks/).

**2**) Are you using **regularization**? Check [regularization](https://towardsdatascience.com/regularization-in-machine-learning-76441ddcf99a).

*Note: These two are one of the two important things to utilize. This list may be a lot longer if you dig deeper.*

Furthermore, there may be some problems in your dataset. For example:

- Your test-train split may be not suitable for your case.
- Your dataset may be too small to train a network. Maybe you should generate or collect more data.(*Eg: if you're classifying images, you can flip the images or use some augmentation techniques to artificially increase the size of your dataset.*

My overall suggestion is to understand *What are the main reasons causing overfitting in machine learning?* since the given answers are so limited.

Answer (score 0):

I think overfitting problem, try to generalize your model more by Regulating and using Dropout layers on. You can do another task, maybe there are periodic variation of your inputted datasets, so try to shuffle on your both train and text datasets. I think the problem will solve. Thank you